# Atualização do banco de dados SQL no projeto MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework

Realizei uma mudança de coluna no meu BD SQL em meu projeto feito em ASP.NET MVC.

Mudei uma coluna de `Cliente_RG (INT)` para `Cliente_Bairro (String)`. No SQL ficou OK a mudança. No projeto, em todas as tabelas (acho) as associações foram alteradas.

Quando eu preencho os campos no meu projeto MVC na hora de salvar no BD resulta em erro dizendo que não foi encontrado a coluna `Cliente_RG`. Sim, não foi encontrada pq eu fiz alteração na tabela. Como eu faço essa alteração para que o meu projeto ASP.NET MVC entenda o novo nome da coluna?

Apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro ao executar o `db.Estacionamento_Cliente.Add(model);`:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: \r\nThe relationship 'EstacionamentoEventos_HOMModel.FK_Comprovante_Cliente_Id_Cliente' was not loaded because the type 'EstacionamentoEventos_HOMModel.Estacionamento_Cliente' is not available.\r\nThe following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:\r\nThe required property 'Cliente_RG' does not exist on the type 'Estacionamento.Models.Estacionamento_Cliente'.\r\n\r\n\r\nThe relationship 'EstacionamentoEventos_HOMModel.FK_Reserva_Cliente_Id_Cliente' was not loaded because the type 'EstacionamentoEventos_HOMModel.Estacionamento_Cliente' is not available.\r\nThe following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:\r\nThe required property 'Cliente_RG' does not exist on the type 'Estacionamento.Models.Estacionamento_Cliente'.\r\n\r\n\r\nThe relationship 'EstacionamentoEventos_HOMModel.FK_Veiculo_Cliente_Id_Cliente' was not loaded because the type 'EstacionamentoEventos_HOMModel.Estacionamento_Cliente' is not available.\r\nThe following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:\r\nThe required property 'Cliente_RG' does not exist on the type 'Estacionamento.Models.Estacionamento_Cliente'.\r\n\r\n

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido. Era o arquivo com extensão .EDMX. Após atualização dele tudo funcionou.